# jquery .html('') not working as I expect

Tags: jquery

I have this code...

```
$(".loadMsg").load('modalAnsmessages.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&t=r',function(){ 
    $('#preloader').fadeOut();
    $(".modal_dialog .content").css({ 'background-color': '#eeeeee' }); 
    setTimeout("$.fancybox.resize();",500);     
});
```

which works fine. Later I run this code...

```
$(".p_close").click( function(){
    $(".loadMsg").html('');
    $(".loadMsgOpen").show();
    $(".modal_dialog .content").css({ 'background-color': '#ffffff' });
    setTimeout("$.fancybox.resize();",500);  
});
```

... that code at first glance appears to run fine; however, I don't think the `$(".loadMsg").html('');` is working as I expected. Each time I run the first block of code, each of the previous contents of `.loadMSG` shows momentarily until it finally gets through all previous instances and stops. Sometimes it stops at the correct one and sometimes not.

What I would like to have happen is that when `$(".p_close").click` is run, I would like all memory of `$(".loadMsg")` to be gone. I thought `$(".loadMsg").html('');` would do that but apparently I am wrong.

Comment: use `$(".loadMsg").empty()` instead. `.html('')` is a wrapper for `.empty().append()`

Comment: Tried `.empty()` but had no success. Thanks @BradM for the idea though.

Comment: I didn't imply using `.empty()` as a solution, just as more precise code. I don't know exactly what you are attempting to do with your code, but my suggestion is to keep everything hidden and only show it when ready. It appears you a bug in some code not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) function instead:

> This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements,
>   but also any text within the set of matched elements.

```
$(".p_close").click( function(){
    $(".loadMsg").empty();
    $(".loadMsgOpen").show();
    $(".modal_dialog .content").css({ 'background-color': '#ffffff' });
    setTimeout("$.fancybox.resize();",500);  
});
```

Comment: Why would this work though? .html('') already does .empty() to the element.

Comment: Tried `.empty()` but had no success. Looks like @BradM was right.

Comment: @G-J `empty()`, as well as `remove()` or `html()` will remove child elements from the DOM. That means they're gone -- good luck trying to get them back unless you've explicitly tried to. In order to do any more we will need to see a working example. Can you fit the problem code into a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. I am very new to jquery so am walking kinda blind through the code... kinda making "educated" guesses at what the code is doing. Thanks for being patient with me. @BinaryTox1n - Not sure what jsFiddle is.

Comment: @G-J [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a website where you can test and update code live within a webpage. It is a very valuable tool for enabling us at SO to help you solve code problems. Often, in trying to put your code into a fiddle, you will solve the problem yourself.